# Create a mysql event with condition

Tags: mysql, events

I currently have a mysql database where I keep data about rented books. When somebody rents a book, I save on the database an expiration date.

So, I want to create an mysql event to update the book status when it is not returned in time. How can I create this event?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
CREATE EVENT `EXPIRAR` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1
 HOUR STARTS '2016-07-16 00:00:00.000000' ENDS '2018-07-29 
00:00:00.000000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO DO IF 
mtl_aluguel.dataLimite=CURRENT_DATE THEN
        UPDATE mtl_aluguel SET mtl_aluguel.estado='Expirou'
    END IF
```

But I'm getting Syntax errors on the IF.

mtl_aluguel is the name of my table.

Comment: your event doesnt make any sense. read up on getting data out of tables or whatnot. I have 3 links next to each other off of my profile page for event stuff. Perhaps they will help (the first one is pretty advanced). So forget that one for now. The 2nd and 3rd ones are rather easy and stuff you will need to know to get the thing to fire or save you time and trouble. Note that in cheap hosting plans, events are typically unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Drew said, my event doesnt make any sense. So I updated it:

```
CREATE EVENT `EXPIRAR` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1
 HOUR STARTS '2016-07-16 00:00:00.000000' ENDS '2018-07-29 
00:00:00.000000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE mtl_aluguel SET mtl_aluguel.estado='Expirou' WHERE mtl_aluguel.dataLimite = CURDATE() AND mtl_aluguel.estado!= 'Expirou'
```